# replace all month in words to digits in a column of a data frame

Tags: python, pandas, python-re

`Month` column in data frame `df` contains both digits and words. I want to convert all words to digits using `replace`. I can't figure out what went wrong with below code. Anyone can help? Thank you!

```
>>>df['Month'].unique()
```

`array(['03', '6', '7', '9', '2', '5', '10', '3', '4', '8', '1', '07', '06', '11', '12', '08', '02', '09', '01', '04', 'April', 'May', 'Feb', 'February', 'October', 'Jan', 'July', 'December', 'September', 'Mar', 'August', 'Sep', 'Nov', 'June', 'Dec', 'Oct', 'January', 'Jun', 'Aug', 'Jul', 'Apr', 1], dtype=object)`

```
>>>m = {'January':1, 'February': 2, 'March': 3, 'April': 4, 'May': 5, 'June': 6, 'July': 7, 'August': 8, 
      'September': 9, 'October': 10, 'November': 11, 'December': 12,
     'Jan':1, 'Feb': 2, 'Mar': 3, 'Apr': 4, 'Jun': 6, 'Jul': 7, 'Aug': 8, 
      'Sep': 9, 'Oct': 10, 'Nov': 11, 'Dec': 12}

>>>df['Month'] = df['Month'].str.replace('(^[A-Z][a-z]+)', lambda x:m[str(x.groups()[0])])
```

```
>>>df['Month'].unique()
```

`array(['03', '6', '7', '9', '2', '5', '10', '3', '4', '8', '1', '07', '06', '11', '12', '08', '02', '09', '01', '04', nan], dtype=object)`

Comment: The above should also have worked. Anyone got any idea?

Comment: you cab also use the map function for series, using the dictionary you provided, the function will map the values to the keys https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html

Answer (score 2):

I figured a simpler way without using regular expression:

```
df.replace({'Month': m})
```